# How can I plot a 3D-plane in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to plot a plane using a vector that I calculated from 3 points where:

```
pointA = [0,0,0];
pointB = [-10,-20,10];
pointC = [10,20,10];

plane1 = cross(pointA-pointB, pointA-pointC)
```

How do I plot 'plane1' in 3D?

Comment: i believe there is a SE site for matlab.

Comment: nope, my mistake -> http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38040/matlab

Comment: You'll most likely need to generate a bunch of points that are in the plane, and then plot those using `surf` or some similar function...

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461869/how-to-plot-a-plane-in-matlab-or-scipy-matplotlib

Answer (score 32):

Here's an easy way to plot the plane using `fill3`:

```
points=[pointA' pointB' pointC']; % using the data given in the question
fill3(points(1,:),points(2,:),points(3,:),'r')
grid on
alpha(0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: `fill3` take `X,Y,Z` as input and not 3 points. Take a look at the plane you drew, it doesn't pass through `(0,0,0)`. You drew a plane that passes through `(0,-10,10)`, `(0, -20,20)` and `(0,10,10)`

Comment: According to Matlab documentation (2nd line for fill3) "fill3(X,Y,Z,C) fills three-dimensional polygons. X, Y, and Z triplets specify the polygon vertices". I did made a mistake though in the way I input the points to `fill3` (wrong dimension used), and this is now corrected. thanks for noticing. I still think a one liner is nicer than several lines...

Comment: That's ok, you got my upvote anyway, I just wanted you to correct the mistake :)

Answer (score 16):

You have already calculated the normal vector. Now you should decide what are the limits of your plane in `x` and `z` and create a rectangular patch.

*An explanation* : Each plane can be characterized by its normal vector `(A,B,C)` and another coefficient `D`. The equation of the plane is `AX+BY+CZ+D=0`. Cross product between two differences between points, `cross(P3-P1,P2-P1)` allows finding `(A,B,C)`. In order to find `D`, simply put any point into the equation mentioned above:

```
   D = -Ax-By-Cz;
```

Once you have the equation of the plane, you can take 4 points that lie on this plane, and draw the patch between them.

[image]

```
normal = cross(pointA-pointB, pointA-pointC); %# Calculate plane normal
%# Transform points to x,y,z
x = [pointA(1) pointB(1) pointC(1)];  
y = [pointA(2) pointB(2) pointC(2)];
z = [pointA(3) pointB(3) pointC(3)];

%Find all coefficients of plane equation    
A = normal(1); B = normal(2); C = normal(3);
D = -dot(normal,pointA);
%Decide on a suitable showing range
xLim = [min(x) max(x)];
zLim = [min(z) max(z)];
[X,Z] = meshgrid(xLim,zLim);
Y = (A * X + C * Z + D)/ (-B);
reOrder = [1 2  4 3];
figure();patch(X(reOrder),Y(reOrder),Z(reOrder),'b');
grid on;
alpha(0.3);
```

Comment: @Eric, true, it should have other cases for zeroes or close to zeroes coefficients.

Comment: See my answer for another solution

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with:

```matlab
function [x, y, z] = plane_surf(normal, dist, size)

    normal = normal / norm(normal);
    center = normal * dist;
    
    tangents = null(normal') * size;
    
    res(1,1,:) = center + tangents * [-1;-1]; 
    res(1,2,:) = center + tangents * [-1;1]; 
    res(2,2,:) = center + tangents * [1;1]; 
    res(2,1,:) = center + tangents * [1;-1];
    
    x = squeeze(res(:,:,1));
    y = squeeze(res(:,:,2));
    z = squeeze(res(:,:,3));
    
end
```

Which you would use as:

```matlab
pointA = [0; 0; 0]; % <- Use column vectors instead of the row vectors from the question
pointB = [-10; -20; 10];
pointC = [10; 20; 10];
normal = cross(pointA-pointB, pointA-pointC);
dist = dot(normal, pointA)

[x, y, z] = plane_surf(normal, dist, 30);
surf(x, y, z);
```

Which plots a square of side length 60 on the plane in question:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to the answer given by Andrey Rubshtein, his code works perfectly well except at B=0. Here is the edited version of his code

**Below Code works when A is not 0**

```
normal = cross(pointA-pointB, pointA-pointC); 
x = [pointA(1) pointB(1) pointC(1)];  
y = [pointA(2) pointB(2) pointC(2)];
z = [pointA(3) pointB(3) pointC(3)];  
A = normal(1); B = normal(2); C = normal(3);
D = -dot(normal,pointA);
zLim = [min(z) max(z)];
yLim = [min(y) max(y)];
[Y,Z] = meshgrid(yLim,zLim);
X = (C * Z + B * Y + D)/ (-A);
reOrder = [1 2  4 3];
figure();patch(X(reOrder),Y(reOrder),Z(reOrder),'r');
grid on;
alpha(0.3);
```

**Below Code works when C is not 0**

```
normal = cross(pointA-pointB, pointA-pointC); 
x = [pointA(1) pointB(1) pointC(1)];  
y = [pointA(2) pointB(2) pointC(2)];
z = [pointA(3) pointB(3) pointC(3)];  
A = normal(1); B = normal(2); C = normal(3);
D = -dot(normal,pointA);
xLim = [min(x) max(x)];
yLim = [min(y) max(y)];
[Y,X] = meshgrid(yLim,xLim);
Z = (A * X + B * Y + D)/ (-C);
reOrder = [1 2  4 3];
figure();patch(X(reOrder),Y(reOrder),Z(reOrder),'r');
grid on;
alpha(0.3);
```

Comment: why do you use reOrder? @krishna-chaitanya