# Plot 3D plane given equations in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, mesh

I want to plot 2 3D planes for the equations given below :

```
x + y + z = 1
2x - y = 0
```

For 1st equation, I plotted it using `meshgrid` as :

```
[x y] = meshgrid(-5:0.5:5);  
z = 1 - x - y  
mesh(x,y,z)
```

But for 2nd equation, z is not given i.e. z can be anything, then how do I plot plane for this ?

Comment: A HOLD ON might work - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/hold.html

Comment: look at the second answer: [How can I plot a 3D-plane in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464304/how-can-i-plot-a-3d-plane-in-matlab) and also [here](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jmr/241/lines_planes.html)!

Comment: @Divakar : problem is not that, problem is I don't know how to create plane for 2nd equation, 1st equation was just for illustration.

Comment: @thewaywewalk : none of the link contains this type of equation. For 2nd equation, the plane is absolutely verttcal, in 2D setting, it is analogous to equation x=0, where we would plot y axis, and I even don't know how to do that.

Comment: When x=0, you plot the y-axis because it is true for all of y.  Same here - you plot this plane across all of z.  So choose a start and end point for z for your plot, and do the same as you did before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments are correct. It is more of a math problem. You draw a line `2x - y = 0` and translate it for any `z` value to create a plane.

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(-5:0.5:5);  
Zv = @(x,y) 1 - x - y;
mesh(x,y,Zv(x,y));

hold on

[x, z] = meshgrid(-5:0.5:5);
Yv = @(x) 2*x;
mesh(x,Yv(x),z);

hold off
```