# Matlab plot 3D plane from equation

Tags: matlab, plot

Is there an equivalent of `refline` for plotting planes in 3D in MATLAB? For example, to plot a plane with the equation `ax+by+cz+d=0`, is there a single function?

Comment: [`fill3`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill3.html), [`surf`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) etc. Have a look at these three questions: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464304/how-can-i-plot-a-3d-plane-in-matlab), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22123996/2338750) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461869/plot-a-plane-based-on-a-normal-vector-and-a-point-in-matlab-or-matplotlib). Find a place to put the end-points in each dimension based in the equation...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3461941/3169868