# How to plot vertical plane in 3D in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have a function f(x,y) such that

f(x,y) = h(x,y), if x-y<-0.5

f(x,y) = g(x,y), if -0.5<=x-y<0

f(x,y) = k(x,y), if x-y>=0

I want to plot this in 3D space (x,y,z), where z is for the value of f(x,y). In addition, I also want to generate vertical planes like x-y = -0.5, x-y=0 and plot them in the same 3D space so that I can see how f(x,y) changes in different regions in (x,y). How can I plot these together in one 3D plot in matlab?

Comment: Do you have examples for `h(x,y)`, `g(x,y)`, and `k(x,y)`?

Comment: @gnovice in my problem, they are very complicated expressions. But here you can just treat them as, for example: h(x,y)= x^2+y^2, g(x,y)=5x+4y and k(x,y)= x*y

Comment: related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464304/how-can-i-plot-a-3d-plane-in-matlab/13464931#13464931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to generate a grid of `x` and `y` points at which to evaluate your function `f(x,y)`. You can do this using [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html). For example, this will create 201-by-201 point grids from -1 to 1 for both `x` and `y`:

```
[x, y] = meshgrid(-1:0.01:1);
```

Now you can fill a matrix `z` with the results of `f(x,y)`, evaluating each part at different subsets of grid points using [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
z = 5.*x+4.*y;                       % Use g(x,y) as default fill value
index = ((x-y) < -0.5);              % Logical index of grid points for h(x,y)
z(index) = x(index).^2+y(index).^2;  % Evaluate h(x,y) at index points
index = ((x-y) >= 0);                % Logical index of grid points for k(x,y)
z(index) = x(index).*y(index);       % Evaluate k(x,y) at index points
```

Now you can plot `z` using [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html):

```
surf(x, y, z, 'EdgeColor', 'none');  % Plots surface without edge lines
```

Then you can generate corner coordinates for the planes and plot them with [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13464304/52738) linked in [a comment from bla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638505/how-to-plot-vertical-plane-in-3d-in-matlab#comment86285307_49638505) for more details). Here's one way to generate them (making them red with some alpha transparency):

```
xPlane = [-1 1 1 -1];      % X coordinates of plane corners, ordered around the plane
yPlane1 = xPlane+0.5;      % Corresponding y coordinates for plane 1
yPlane2 = xPlane;          % Corresponding y coordinates for plane 2
zPlane = [-10 -10 10 10];  % Z coordinates of plane corners
hold on;                   % Add to existing plot
patch(xPlane, yPlane1, zPlane, 'r', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);  % Plot plane 1
patch(xPlane, yPlane2, zPlane, 'r', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);  % Plot plane 2
```

And here's the resulting plot:

[image]