# matlab plotting linear regression on a 3D scatter plot

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression, least-squares

I am new to matlab and have just started on the UBC AI course. I used the least squares algorithm to generate the weights for the [data-set](http://neuron-ai.tuke.sk/vascak/predmety/UI/test1.txt) I'm working with and the weights ive generated are `[ 0.3400 ,-0.0553 , -0.0667]`.

Using the weights generated I predicted the value of y against the current data set (predictions are shown as x and the actual values are shown as circles). This brings me to the problem of trying to visualize the regression plane using the weights and the data I have. So basically my problem is how do you visualize the linear regression plane using the data I now have collected, or am I missing something?

and do the weights generated correspond to the y-intercept, slope and its orientation? If so how do they fit into the 2D plane equation?

[image]

Comment: I've posted an answer for visualizing the regression plane. However, your outcome is binary, so you should be rounding any prediction above 0.5 to 1, and any prediction below 0.5 to 0. A more interesting visualization might be the cutoff line, where on one side points are predicted to be 1's, and on the other side, they are 0. To visualize this line, instead of the plane `y = a*x1 + b*x2 + c`, instead plot the line `0.5 = a*x1 + b*x2 + c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those weights you've generated are your regression coefficients, `Beta0, Beta1` and `Beta2`. If `y` is your vertical axis and `x1`, `x2` are your features, or horizontal axes, they give you this equation for the plane:

```
y = Beta0 + Beta1*x1 + Beta2*x2
```

Which for you is:
    y = 0.3400 + -0.0553*x1 + -0.0667*x2

As for how to visualize this plane, we can find the answer at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461869/how-to-plot-a-plane-in-matlab-or-scipy-matplotlib)

```
weights = [ 0.3400 ,-0.0553 , -0.0667];
[x1,x2]=ndgrid(-5:1:5,-5:1:5);
y = weights(1) + weights(2)*x1 + weights(3)*x2

figure
surf(x1,x2,y);
```