# count point between two surfaces

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've a little problem concerning python.

I've follow this subject : [How to draw planes from a set of linear equations in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410733/how-to-draw-planes-from-a-set-of-linear-equations-in-python)

I created two surface, and between this 2 surfaces, **i want to count the number of points**. I've no idea to proccess, can you help me ?

I think that it's not really complicated, but i don't know how to get this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page for how to create an answerable question, with a minimal but complete example.

Comment: Are you asking how to find the intersection of two planes? That's a line, unless the planes are parallel and don't intersect at all. There will be an infinite number of points.

Comment: No, i've created a a plot with many points, and i've traced two planes following a right. I want to calcul the number of points between the two planes. I have no example, just imagine that in the link that i share in my first post, you have a cloud of points, and you want to count the number of this point between the two planes.

Comment: I don't want to write your code but I can tell you that you can compute the oriented distance of a point from the two planes.  With a proper definition of positive distance a point is inside the 2 planes if the product of the 2 distances is negative.