# How does one draw the X = 0 plane using matplotlib (mpl3d)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Here is an answer that lets one plot a plane using `matplotlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12503243/3486684), but if one uses the vector `[1, 0, 0]`, nothing gets plotted! This makes sense, because of the way the code is set up (meshgrid is on X-Y plane, and then Z points determine the surface.

So, how can I plot the X = 0 plane using matplotlib?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is less generic than the example that you linked, but it does the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

yy, zz = np.meshgrid(range(2), range(2))
xx = yy*0

ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz)
plt.show()
```

[image]