# Matplotlib: how to draw a vertical plane in 3D figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a vertical plane defined by

`5 = x + y`

in a 3D figure, using Matplotlib.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394305/how-does-one-draw-the-x-0-plane-using-matplotlib-mpl3d) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461869/plot-a-plane-based-on-a-normal-vector-and-a-point-in-matlab-or-matplotlib/12503243#12503243), but no chance.  I also found `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.line_2d_to_3d` at [this link](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.line_2d_to_3d.html), which says

> Convert a 2D line to 3D

Looked promising to me, but I could not figure out how to use it.

Now, how would you modify the following code to achieve my objective?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
ys = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
Z # ?????????

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your mistake is that you define `xs` and `ys` as independent variables, while they are dependent (x + y = 5). `zs` is here independent:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
zs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

X, Z = np.meshgrid(xs, zs)
Y = 5 - X

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]