# Plot maximum-margin hyperplane in 3-space with Python

Tags: python, plot, machine-learning, svm, data-science

I have found this really cool notebook on SVM :

https://github.com/jakevdp/sklearn_tutorial/blob/master/notebooks/03.1-Classification-SVMs.ipynb

But was a bit frustrated 'cause it doesn't show how to plot the maximum-margin in 3-space. I've tried my best but have no clue about how to do it... For instance I'd like to plot it on the following reprsentation (which is taken from the notebook):

[image]

Also, if suport vectors could be encircled it would be the sherry on the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good question, however the notebook provided is actually "lying". This not how kernel works, and while this visualization is cool, it is not what happens "inside SVM". Lets put this aside though and focus on how to plot 3D separation hyperplane in this projected space (which **is not** RBF projected space).

All you have to do is:

1. Fit **linear** SVM to the 3D data used for this plot.
2. Extract weights (clf.coefs_) and bias (clf.intercept_)
3. [Plot 3d hyperplane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461869/plot-a-plane-based-on-a-normal-vector-and-a-point-in-matlab-or-matplotlib) with normal (clf.coefs_) and distance from the origin (clf.intercept_)

Comment: Thx a lot lejlot, I'm stuck at step 3 though. I have 2 values for `clf.coefs_` and one for `clf.intercept_`, when I need to input 3 for normal (a,b,c) and 3 for point (x,y,z), according to the link you posted.

Comment: you have to fit on 3d data you plotted, which, in your case is x, y, k(x, y), thus you will have **three** coefs

Comment: You're completely right thx, `clf.coefs_` provides 3 values and not 2. Thanks to your help I managed to [plot the hyperplane](https://s23.postimg.org/w1bzmkg7v/index.png).

Comment: [Here](http://www.novagen.tech/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/JupyterVSZeppelin.pdf) you can find my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
```

```
X_1_2, y = make_circles(100, factor = .1, noise=.1)
X_3 = np.exp(-(X_1_2[:,0] ** 2 + X_1_2[:,1] ** 2))
X = np.insert(X_1_2, 2, X_3, axis=1)
```

```
clf = SVC(kernel='linear').fit(X,y)
```

```
w = clf.coef_
w1 = w [:, 0]
w2 = w [:, 1]
w3 = w [:, 2]
b = clf.intercept_
sv = clf.support_vectors_
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(-1,2), range(-1,2))
zz = (-w1 * xx - w2 * yy - b) * 1. /w3
```

```
%matplotlib notebook
plt3d = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
plt3d.plot_wireframe(xx, yy, zz, rstride=1, cstride=1, color='purple')
plt3d.scatter3D(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2], c=y, s=50, cmap='winter')
plt3d.scatter3D(sv[:, 0], sv[:, 1], sv[:, 2], s=150)
plt.show()
```

[image]